# In Java to find and retrieve Object of a particular Class from a ArrayList of Objects

Tags: java, list

I have a ArrayList of Objects. Need to find if that list of Objects has an Object of a particular Class of interest and retrieve it. Is there any built in function or other utilities in Java which can retrieve this Object directly. Please note I am looking to avoid looping using iterator.

Example:

```
List<Object> _list = new ArrayList<Object>();

//I am creating Objects using reflection and adding it to list
_list.add(object);


//Now i have a Class object of a particular class say ToolRun and pass it as argument
public Object getObjectFromList(Class c){
  //this get function on list should find if list contains any Object of  
  //given Class name and retrieve it if found else should return null
  return _list.get(c.getCanonicalName()) }
```

Comment: Actually, some (pseudo) code would help

Comment: Detailed body and title

Comment: you should definitly try this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What more detail needs to be given i don't know, downvoter should write the comment as why down vote ? Helps for better post, i feel stymied before posting questions nowadays

Answer (score 3):

A Java 8 aproach could be:

```
    public List removeLastMovieWithGenre(List list, Class filterClazz){
       return (List) list.parallelStream()
            .filter(element -> filterClazz.isInstance(element))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

It returns a sublist of objects with the parameter class.

Answer (score 0):

`instanceof` keyword returns true if an object is of given class.

**Example :**

```
Student s = new Student();
System.out.ptinln(s instanceof Student);
```

> Output : true

So you can do like this

```
List list = getList();
if(list.get(0) instanceof Student) {
 System.out.println("STUDENT");
} else if(list.get(0) instanceof Teacher) {
 System.out.println("TEACHER");
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is like going through the loop in case of lot of Objects in the List, was thinking if there is some built-in method or work around to get Object directly.

Comment: I don't think there is any built in method for this purpose